# jssor - parameter to define the duration of the static position before playing out

Tags: jssor

I couldn't find the answer through the documentation.
How to set the d, du, du2 parameters so that I can obtain:

Here is my understanding (please correct me if I am wrong)...

1. I start an animation after a certain time (compared to previous animation stop): **d**
2. Duration of the play-in animation: **du**  (time it takes to run the play-in animation I guess)
3. Duration of the "static position":  ***????***  <== I don't find any parameter for this
4. Duration of the play-out animation: **du2** (time it takes to run the
   play-out animation I guess)

My objective is to have 2 texts.  Text1 plays-in, stays a while and plays-out, while Text2   would, for example stay longer on the screen before playing out.

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. And you understand well.

Re 3:
Please use **b2** to reach the goal.