# how to set the duration of a caption in jssor

Tags: jssor

I am setting up a slider with captions. I want to display a slide, reveal a caption, leave the caption visible for most of the time the slide is visible, remove the caption, move to the next slide, then repeat for subsequent slide(s). I cannot find a parameter to allow me to set the duration of the captions visibility. I understand the following:

```
d: is the delay before starting the animation 
du: duration of play-in animation
du2: duration of play-out animation
```

Another question ([jssor - parameter to define the duration of the static position before playing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995467/jssor-parameter-to-define-the-duration-of-the-static-position-before-playing-o)) contained a terse reply referring to 'b2' but this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. The reference to 'b2' appears to be correct. In my testing of that parameter I had the syntax wrong so it appeared not to work. If you include b2=n, then the caption remains visible for the period n (where n is milliseconds).